# Emails going to spam - Gmail / Hotmail / Outlook?

Tags: centos, email, postfix

Right, sorry if I come across a frustrated but I'm actually raged that I haven't got this sorted yet.

We moved to a dedicated server 2 months ago, from a shared server (which had no issues with emails), the moment we moved over, everything was configured but every single damn email went to junk - Ok, so I set up SPF records, DKIM etc and that seemed to fix the hotmail/outlook issue... GMAIL - horrid.

I've correctly configured reverse DNS, DMARC, DKIM, SPF records and emails are still going to gmail junk - I've tried contacting Gmail (approx 15 times now) using their bulk delivery contact form thing and had no response.

I'm literally at an end now, I'm confident everything is set up correctly as I've used several email testing services, checked blacklists and nothing - but no one can seem to figure out including myself why this is happening.

One thing that has changed is when we moved over to the dedicated server is the default hostname was provided by the host, I changed the hostname to our domain name and proceeded to point the DNS to the updated hostname, all looks well but the reverse dns still points to the default one, and theres literally no other setting i can change

Thanks for reading, hope you can help :)

Comment: PS. We're attempting to send sales confirmation emails (Magento)

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Reverse DNS is set up correctly
- Your domain is not on any public blacklists
- Gmail has not blacklisted you

If those things are addressed, you should be good to go. Keep in mind that you have no control of gmail's blacklist. You can follow [these instructions](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/gmail-blacklist-removal/#gmail_blacklist_removal) to get your IP removed.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Cantelope - I've checked and we're not on any blacklists, I've also checked reverse DNS and our IP  resolves the default hostname the dedicated server came with - I've changed every setting possible and it never changes. 

In regards to the gmail blacklist, like I said in my post i've literally filled in that form 15 times and still haven't received a response off gmail

Answer (score 0):

There is a break even point of cost for effort against the amount of time that you're going to put into solving these problems.

And not just solving them today, but solving them again the next time you scale, or change servers, or the next time an IP you send from makes it onto an RBL, or the next time *X* mail provider changes the rules.

My suggestion would be to leave the mail sending to the people doing it professionally. Any one of the many service providers that charge you per thousand mails sent. Many are free for small volumes of mail.

Otherwise, if you're really interested in doing this all yourself you'll need to start by getting the full headers of the messages that made it into the spam folder. Take a look at the `X-` headers. You will find some that include details of what rules/lists were hit and that will indicate what you need to do to solve the problem (for today anyway...)